# how do i get the marked part Firestore functions javascript

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

how do i get the marked part Firestore functions javascript ?

[image]

```
exports.observeFollow = functions.firestore.document("/TakipEdilen/{takipEdilenID}").onCreate((snapshot, context)=>{ 

  var takipEdilen = context.params.takipEdilenID;


  return admin.firestore().collection("TakipEdilen").doc(takipEdilen).get().then(function(snapshot) {
    var takipEden = Object.keys.snapshot;
 

    return admin.firestore().collection("Firmalar").doc(takipEden).get().then((snaps)=>{ 

      var alan = snaps.data();

      return admin.firestore().collection("Firmalar").doc(takipEdilen).get().then((snaps)=>{ 

        var alan2 = snaps.data();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a generated field name in your `` document. You can get the field name with:

```
exports.observeFollow = functions.firestore.document("/TakipEdilen/{takipEdilenID}").onCreate((snapshot, context)=>{ 

  var takipEdilen = context.params.takipEdilenID;

  const data = snapshot.data();
  Object.keys(data).forEach((key) => {
    console.log(key);
  });
  ...
```